# How to pass model from one Action method to another using RedirectToAction in asp.net MVC ? I am getting null model though I send a populated model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class JobSeekerViewModel. I want to Send it from Action method Index to Details. but whenever I send I get null values. but my model is populated.

```
public class JobSeekerViewModel
{
    public user userJobSeeker { get; set; }

    public employee employeeJobSeeker { get; set; }
       }
}

index(login log1)
{
    Return View(log1);
}


[HttpPost]
index (login log1) 
{
    JobSeekerViewModel js = new JobSeekerViewModel();
    js.userJobSeeker = log1.userJobSeeker;
    js.employeeJobSeeker = log1.employeeJobSeeker;
    return Details(js);
}
Details(JobSeekeerViewModel js)
{
     Return View(js);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Index

```
        TempData["jobSeeker"] = jobSeeker;
```

Details

```
        JobSeekerViewModel jobSeeker = (JobSeekerViewModel)TempData["jobSeeker"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
index (JobSeekerViewModel js) 
{
   return RedirectToAction("Details", new{model = js});
}
```

Comment: still getting null values. :(

Comment: what is the name parameter that the method receives, replace it with the model i posted

Comment: I am sorry. my Index receives another model Login. but I want to send JobSeekerViewModel to details.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, I hope you get the idea.

```
Index (login log1) 
{
  //get your JobSeekerViewModel and then use it.

   return RedirectToAction("Details", new { model = jobSeekerViewModel });
}

Details(JobSeekerViewModel model) 
{
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: yup. my controller is not null. Now I am getting a peculiar error. 
that is 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'job_management_two.Models.JobSeekerViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'job_management_two.Models.Login'

Comment: This error occurs when it is passed a different type object than is expected by your Action or View.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `redirectToAction` the data is not preserved between the controller and the view and hence you get `null`

Either use `TempData` or call the method `details()` directly instead of `redirectToAction`

Read this for examples : [Can we pass model as a parameter in RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505674/can-we-pass-model-as-a-parameter-in-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 0):

if your action is in the same controller you don't need to call `RedirectToAction`.

simply call action like:

```
index (login log1) 
{
    JobSeekerViewModel js = new JobSeekerViewModel();
    js.userJobSeeker = log1.userJobSeeker;
    js.employeeJobSeeker = log1.employeeJobSeeker;
    return Details(js);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To Send model from one action to another action -

In Action to set model:

```
TempData["myId"] = myIdToTransfer;
```

In another Action get model:

```
String userID = TempData["myID"].ToString;
```

> To send model from an action to view

In action to set model:

```
ViewBag.myId = myIdToTransfer;
```

In View to get model:

```
@Html.ViewBag.myId
```