# RedirectToAction with model paramter or TempData model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

*I want to pass model member values to this controller from RedirectToAction*

```
public ActionResult UserRegistraion1(UserProfilePL objpl)
```

*Using TempData model to pass on this RedirectToAction i don't want to make individual TempData to insert every model member on it single TempData model to retrieve at this UserProfilePL how can i achieve this.*

*Model passing to this Action below.*

```
UserProfilePL objpl = new UserProfilePL();
ViewBag.msg = objpl.Code;
                objpl.LoginID = emailID;
                objpl.FBGMid = ID;
                objpl.type = type;
                objpl.Name = name;
                objpl.ImageUrl = ImgUrl1;

                //TempData[""] = 

                return RedirectToAction("UserRegistraion1", "Home");
```

*I want to pass objpl model into this RedirectToAction without individual TempData.*

Comment: You do not need _individual TempData to insert every model member_. you can just add the model to `TempData`. But `TempData` only lasts one request, so it means that if the user refreshes the page, the data will be lost. Pass the `ID` of the model to the `UserRegistraion` method and get the data object from the database again.

Comment: Include your UserRegistration View code with question.

Comment: Sir Stephen Muecke this won't work as ID is created within the database and email ID is fetched from Facebook and Gmail which is not possible for me to get data from database which i would say don't exist as it is for new registration

Comment: Sir  Ajinder Singh i have updated the code as you can see what i want from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this in your Action method. See I'm keeping the complete Model in Tempdata

```
TempData["myObject"] = objpl;
```

Then inside your UserRegistraion Action method,

```
if (TempData["myObject"] != null)
{
    UserProfilePL profile = (UserProfilePL) TempData["myObject"];
    //rest code
}
```

To keep single value in TempData,

```
TempData["myEmail"] = emailID;
```

Then you can retrive the value in UserRegistraion Action method.

Comment: How do i pass it on return RedirectToAction("UserRegistraion1", "Home"); with TempData model

Comment: There is no need to pass this TempData. You just need to write this before this line of your Method. RedirectToAction("UserRegistraion1", "Home");

Comment: Then u can automatically fetch the data in UserRegistraion1 Method. I have already wrote the code how to extract data, please check once my answer.

Comment: i understood completely, my concern is that i want to add model TempData value and pass it on this public ActionResult UserRegistraion(UserProfilePL objpl) on this method

Comment: RedirectToAction("UserRegistraion", "Home" , new { TempData["myObject"]}); like this method

Comment: No. U can't pass like this. Then what is use of TempData ??

Comment: Actually i don't want to create a new method to pass TempData i just want to pass model on the RedirectToAction is it possible

Comment: In that case u can return a view with the model data. Ex: return view("UserRegistraion1",objpl);

Comment: What is ur issue with the TempData ? U can't pass a complex object in RedirectToAction(). Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505674/can-we-pass-model-as-a-parameter-in-redirecttoaction

Comment: i found a solution though return View("~/Views/Home/UserRegistraion1",objpl) how do i get the actual path

Comment: That is what I already mentioned here. return view("UserRegistraion1",objpl); This is what u r doing now.

Comment: Yes but error is throwing can't find the path issue

Comment: The view 'UserRegistraion1' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/UserRegistraion1.aspx
~/Views/Home/UserRegistraion1.ascx
~/Views/Shared/UserRegistraion1.aspx
~/Views/Shared/UserRegistraion1.ascx
~/Views/Home/UserRegistraion1.cshtml
~/Views/Home/UserRegistraion1.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/UserRegistraion1.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/UserRegistraion1.vbhtml

Comment: Do u have a UserRegistraion1 View or not ??

Comment: yes of course i have a view with model data as a parameter passing on it

Comment: See, U need to pass by TempData as I mentioned in my answer. Return View("UserRegistraion1",objpl) will only load the view, it wont call the Action Method. U can't pass complex object in RedirectToAction();

Comment: Yeah last time i tried to pass model on redirect but didn't work MVC do have its limitations thank you for your time sir

Comment: You just need to click on mark as answer in my solution and click on upvote button :) Thanks