# Entity Framework : send list between methods in the same controller not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to send a list to this method (inside the same controller)

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult listaExpedientesPOrCriterio(List<Expediente> expedientes)
    {

        ExpedienteListPorCriterio vm = new ExpedienteListPorCriterio(expedientes);
        //List<Expediente> expedientes = db.Expediente.ToList();
        //SelectList Tramitees = new SelectList(expedientes, "Codigo", "FechaCreacion");
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Im using this inside the other method, to send the list

```
return RedirectToAction("listaExpedientesPOrCriterio", "expedientes");
```

but I receive only null. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: You are sending a string, not a list of "expedientes". You can try something like this: return RedirectToAction("listaExpedientesPOrCriterio", new { listOfExpedientes }); where listOfExpedientes is an existing List<Expediente> object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we pass model as a parameter in RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505674/can-we-pass-model-as-a-parameter-in-redirecttoaction)

Comment: I check using that, and now is not getting a null, but it send an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You have `[HttpGet]` action attribute. How you intend to send to it `List<T>` at all? Instead, you have to use `[HttpPost]` and pass data in request's body, but at this case you won't can to `RedirectToAction`. But you can pass your `expedientes` list from one action to another via `TempData` also preserving `[HttpGet]`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AnotherActionName()
{
    //some code...
    TempData["expedientes"] = expedientes;
    return RedirectToAction("listaExpedientesPOrCriterio"/*, "expedientes"*/);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult listaExpedientesPOrCriterio(/*List<Expediente> expedientes*/)
{
    var expedientes = (List<Expediente>)TempData["expedientes"];
    var vm = new ExpedienteListPorCriterio(expedientes);    
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: I will try to use this, Tks. I will let you know if it works.